# Restrict Non-Owners from changing the Collaboration branch of Azure Data Factory using Azure Policy

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-policy

We would like to impose the following restrictions on Azure Data Factory

1. Don't let users change the collaboration branch from develop to anything else.
2. Allow only Owners to change the collaboration branch to any other branch if required.

We were able to achieve the #1 feature using the below policy

```
   {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
      "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories"
        },
        {
          "field": "name",
          "equals": "adfproject-dev-df1"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/repoConfiguration.collaborationBranch",
          "notEquals": "develop"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }   
  } ,
  "parameters": {}
}
```

However, the below rule (within the allOf condition/array for #2 is not working. any pointers would be of great help.

```
 "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/principalRole",
 "notEquals": "Owner"
```

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score -1):

> Instead of having all users in one customer role and then apply policy
> on them, I feel you can consider creating another custom role in which
> you can add users who are allowed to change collaboration branch. And
> don't have Azure policy on the role.

That way this new custom role users are free to change collaboration branch as well.

Comment: We already have custom roles in place. We don't want to control the feature with RBAC. We would like to implement that using Azure Policy. Could you please get some expert on Azure Policy and help us in understanding how to achieve it using Azure Policy?